# sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats shows I have 3 PK indexes after rebuild

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, azure-sql-database

I was checking the fragmentation in the index in one table of my DB with the following query

```
SELECT a.object_id, object_name(a.object_id) AS TableName,
    a.index_id, name AS IndedxName, avg_fragmentation_in_percent
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats
    (DB_ID (N'prod-db')
        , OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Channel]')
        , NULL
        , NULL
        , NULL) AS a
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS b
    ON a.object_id = b.object_id
    AND a.index_id = b.index_id;
GO
```

And discovered that it listed `PK_Channel` 3 times,

| TableName | index_id | IndedxName | object_id | avg_fragmentation_in_percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Channel | 1 | PK_Channel | 1557580587 | 0,01 |
| Channel | 1 | PK_Channel | 1557580587 | 0 |
| Channel | 1 | PK_Channel | 1557580587 | 0 |
| Channel | 3 | idx_Channel_RegisteredTime | 1557580587 | 0,0429737859905458 |

I have rebuilt the index 2 times, so it coincides with that. But is this a good thing? Or is this normal (aka expected behaviour)? Should I "fix" this? if so, how?

It is worth noting that the index `idx_Channel_RegisteredTime` was rebuilt once and no duplication was found in `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats`. Can anyone shed light on this?

Also please notice that when I list the indexes in the Management Studio it only shows `PK_Channel` once, which is what I would expect.

[image: My management studio for the table Channel]

In case it makes any difference or any one is curious, I rebuilt the indexes using the following statement

```
ALTER INDEX PK_Channel ON [dbo].[Channel]
REBUILD
;

ALTER INDEX idx_Channel_RegisteredTime ON [dbo].[Channel]
REBUILD
;
```

Thanks

Comment: check the index_level column ....https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-physical-stats-transact-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have one index, with multiple levels in the B-tree.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-physical-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats`:

> For an index, one row is returned for each level of the B-tree in each partition.

This means that `dm_db_index_physical_stats` will return a row for **each** level of the B-tree. You are joining that onto the **single** row from `sys.indexes`.

Comment: but it seems that every time I rebuild the index I get an extra row of that. Does that mean that my Btree is growing? The amount of rows in that table is quasi constant around 2.5M and it has almost no deletion and very little adds (around 100/day or so), however it seems that every 2 weeks I have fragmentation over 60% is this normal?

Comment: It's quite normal. I wouldn't bother rebuilding an index on an SSD drive unless fragmentation is really bad.